# How to get two cursors in two text-boxes simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created transliteration, which converts strings from Latin to Devanagari. I have two text boxes one for input and another for the result, which is readonly. I want to show cursor in result box also when I type in the input textbox. How can I do that?

[image: Current Output]

Comment: You can either only fake that using CSS, or put either `textarea` in an `iframe`.